# Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate. Could not resolve DartDev snapshot or kernel. (null)

Tags: dart

I have some error while trying to run dart file, saying

```
Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate. Could not resolve DartDev snapshot or kernel.
(null).
```

NOTE: iam not installing flutter

Comment: What operating system are you using? How did you install Dart? What does `dart --version` return in your terminal?

Comment: Iam using windows 10, install from chocolatey the version is 2.17.3

Comment: And what does the command return in full? `dart --version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in my dart SDK, the SDK was corrupt and to solve this issue just delete last installed SDK and install new one.